# Parse json inside csv

Tags: python, json, csv

I have a script which gives output csv like this where the values are not writing to the third column and leaves it empty.

```
name|fail|total|
test1|"{'fail': 0, 'total': 1}"|
test2|"{'fail': 0, 'total': 6}"|
```

I want to write this output to a csv where I want the output in 3 columns of csv. How can I parse the second column and print the values to two different column?

```
name,fail,total
test1,0,1
test2,0,6
```

Here is how I am trying to write this to a csv using python

```
with open('file.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
fieldnames = ['name', 'fail', 'total']
output = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames, delimiter=',')
output.writeheader()
for k, v in lookupTable.iteritems():
    output.writerow({fieldnames[0]: k, fieldnames[1]: v})
```

Can anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

From the output that you get I can conclude that `type(v)` is `dict`, so you need to unpack its values. Here is the for loop that would give you the correct result.

```
keys = ['plan', 'Total', 'Time', 'name', 'createdDate']
fieldnames = ['plan', 'totalDirections', 'stopTime', 'customerName', 'createDate']
row = dict(zip(fieldnames, [data[k] for k in keys]))
output = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames, delimiter=',')
output.writeheader()
output.writerow(row)
```

Comment: But this is not working for me :( I am getting this error.

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "analytics.py", line 48, in <module>
    row = dict(zip(fieldnames, [json_data[k] for k in json_keys]))
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str`

Comment: Sorry I am not able to figure out what mistake I have done. But I am not able to get the output to csv. My list looks something like this. I need a neat csv as an output

`{"createdDate": "2016-04-11 05:23:57", "stopTime": "2016-04-11T00:00:00.000Z", "plan": "Starter", "name": {"fail": "0", "total": "1", "cust": "1mw"}, "directionsTotal": 0}`

Comment: Its printing the contents to a csv. Yet need to rework on how its printing. But its overwriting the added row with new entry instead of adding the new entry to a new row. something like the below image. 

![screenshot 2016-05-01 01 55 00](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/3423533/14938406/e370d6ee-0f3f-11e6-82bd-1c5cb4cb00c7.png)

Comment: here is the code I have been working. http://pastebin.com/LMZD7Xx1
This code gives o/p like below:

{"plan": "Starter", "directionsTotal": 0, "stopTime": "2016-04-11T00:00:00.000Z", "name": {"fail": "0", "total": "1", "cust": "one"}, "createdDate": "2016-04-11&05:23:57"}
{"plan": "Starter", "directionsTotal": 0, "stopTime": "2016-04-29T00:00:00.000Z", "name": {"fail": "0", "total": "300", "cust": "two"}, "createdDate": "2016-04-08&14:20:04"}

I would like this to be saved in a csv file.

Comment: Yeah this worked. thank you. is this a good way to first start open and write the csv and add values as the script executes each one of them?

Answer (score 0):

@user128285 Yeah this works. Can we do the same way for json.dumps?

I have another script where the json.dumps is having the output which should be written to csv.

`print json.dumps(data)` prints the output like below

`{"plan": "yes", "Total": 0, "Time": "2016-04-11T00:00:00.000Z", "name": {"fail": "0", "total": "1", "cName": "red"}, "createdDate": "2016-04-11 05:23:57"}`

Here is how I tried after your suggestion like above to parse the above output to csv:

```
with open('customer_analysis', 'w') as csvfile:
fieldnames = ['plan', 'totalDirections', 'stopTime', 'customerName', 'createDate']
output = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames, delimiter=',')
output.writeheader()
for a, b, c, d, e in json.dumps(data):
output.writerow({fieldnames[0]: a, fieldnames[1]: b, fieldnames[2]: c, fieldnames[3]: d['fail'], fieldnames[4]: d['total'], fieldnames[5]: e})
```

is this correct? or how to correct this?

Comment: When I use the above code snippet, its throwing me 
`ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack` error

Comment: you should explicitly build the dictionary that is passed to writerow.